# Firefox issue for JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, html-table

I have a HTML table of data which is stored on a MySQL database. I am retrieving the data with PHP, and putting it into a HTML table. I then need created a function to sort the data in some of the columns in descending alphabetical order. Below is the function.

While it works perfectly in Chrome, it does not work in Firefox. Can someone please explain why?

```
function dataSort(columnNum) {
  var artDataTable = document.getElementById('table');
  var dataArray = [];

  for (var I = 1; I < artDataTable.rows.length; i++) {
    var r = artDataTable.rows[i];
    var rowData = r.cells[columnNum].innerText;
    dataArray.push([rowData, r]);
  }

  dataArray.sort();
  for (var j = 0; j < dataArray.length; j++) {
    artDataTable.appendChild(dataArray[j][1]);
  }

  dataArray = null;
}
```

Comment: is there any error in firebug console?

Comment: Where / when are you calling this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerText` is [not supported by Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), it's a IE-specific property adopted by Chrome as well.

For support in all modern browsers, use `textContent` instead

```
var rowData = r.cells[columnNum].textContent;
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!

Comment: InnerText is coming to firefox